# Not able to get activity_main.xml file

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I am not able to get the activity_main.xml file in layout. I my code i am not getting

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main.xml);
```

I am getting this error

```
 activity_main cannot be resolved or is not a field.
```

Please explain me what is need to be done to get access.

Comment: If you are developing in Eclipse check the where the xml file is present in the res>layout> folder of your project folder. The layout file is auto generated when you create a new project. The name of the xml file is activity_"your_activity_name".xml (quotes for clarity)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the unwanted imports like `import android.R;`

Check if there are errors in `res folder`. Specially in `string.xml` or `drawable folder files` if no errors means clean your project and try again

Comment: no their are no error on other files. I have cleared the project even then i am getting the same issue. At the same time i have another project in that i am able to access all its XML file in its java file the issue stands in this project.

Comment: Hi that was awesome. How did you get to that? Can you please explain me. "Remove the unwanted imports like import android.R;"

Comment: in your activity click `ctrl`+`shift`+`o`. then all unwanted imports will be gone